# 2D Animation app for Android

Tags: android, animation

I'm looking for an Android app to create 2D animations by drawing. I know **FlipaClip** and **Animation Desk**, but none of them support the feature I'm wanting. I want to be able to have some static layers (like background images and some simple props) that stay through the whole sequence, and have other layers for the actual animating, frame-by-frame.

I found [RoughAnimator](https://www.roughanimator.com/) has what I want, and it also supports more cool features like onion-skinning and ..., but it has 2 problems:

1. Lack of "artistic" options: there are only few brushes.
2. Ey... not good UI

[image]